# How to classify human actions?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, image-recognition, video-classification

I'm quite new to machine learning (I followed the Coursera course of Andrew Ng and now starting deeplearning.ai courses).

I want to classify human actions real-time like:

- Left-arm bended
- Arm above shoulder
- ...

I first did some research for pre-trained models, but I didn't find any.
Because I'm still quite new, I want to have advice about how I should solve this.

1. I thought maybe I need to create for every action enough pictures and from there on I can do image classification.
2. Or I use PoseNet from TensorFlow so that I have the pose estimation points. And from there on I create videos of a couple of seconds with every pose I want to track and I save the estimation points. From there on, I use a classification algorithm (neural network) to classify those points.

What is the most efficient option or are they both bad and is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to go with 1st option. reason is you will get to know much about data and initial stage will find some challenges in developing the model, over a period of time you will get to better results after hypertunning. Please go through [article](http:////https://machinelearningmastery.com/deep-learning-models-for-human-activity-recognition/) , ignore you have already read this article

Comment: Thanks for the article will read this. Any idea how I get a lot of images or how many I actually need?

Comment: Are you looking for label data with images or just images, have found one data set, [link](http://vision.stanford.edu/Datasets/40actions.html).

Comment: Thank you. For me it doesn't matter I can label them myself. Like for example pictures of people bending their arms. When searching for this on google not a lot of pictures show up. In the database you shared per action 280 pictures exist.